# How can I solve the problem with radio buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok guys, I am not able to make those buttons do as they are told. In stead, even before selected, they all just print the same value for the guess variable, if I set it to None, that is printed four times....and I dont know what to do any more. This is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.title("KVIZOMANIJA")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
guess = StringVar()
guess.set("opa")
odg1 = Radiobutton(app,text = "prvi gumbek", variable = guess, value = "a", command =print(guess.get()))
odg1.grid(row=4, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg2 = Radiobutton(app,text="drugi gumbek", variable = guess, value = "b", command = print(guess.get()))
odg2.grid(row=5, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg3 = Radiobutton(app,text="treci gumbek", variable = guess, value = "c", command = print(guess.get()))
odg3.grid(row=6, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg4 = Radiobutton(app,text="cetvrti gumbek", variable = guess, value = "d", command = print(guess.get()))
odg4.grid(row=7, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
root.mainloop()
```

So, this is it....

Answer (score 2):

I probably see your problem: it's because you do not set a function in "command" argument, you set an instruction. You should replace

```
command =print(guess.get())
```

by

```
command=lambda x: print(guess.get())
```

`lambda` is a way to make an anonymous function with only one instruction in it and it returns the result of the instruction.

You can also define a normal function like this:

```py
def get_guess():
    print(guess.get())
```

and

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.title("KVIZOMANIJA")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
guess = StringVar()
guess.set("opa")
odg1 = Radiobutton(app,text = "prvi gumbek", variable = guess, value = "a", command=get_guess)
odg1.grid(row=4, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg2 = Radiobutton(app,text="drugi gumbek", variable = guess, value = "b", command=get_guess)
odg2.grid(row=5, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg3 = Radiobutton(app,text="treci gumbek", variable = guess, value = "c", command=get_guess)
odg3.grid(row=6, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
odg4 = Radiobutton(app,text="cetvrti gumbek", variable = guess, value = "d", command=get_guess)
odg4.grid(row=7, column = 0, columnspan= 2, sticky = W)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok thank you but couldnt you and why cant you do it without lambda? But, this is not my main problem, I will post a question with my main problem because your answer did not solve it.

Comment: You can define a normal function instead of a lambda function.

Comment: my problem is that if loop connected to the values I get from buttons wont work and I cant post a new question yet, 90 minutes thing..

Comment: in command = get_guess dont you need () also? Like, comman = get_guess() ?

Comment: No, because if you add (), then the function will be called when you define it.